# How to get color on dropdown of select on Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

I have tried to get color on dropdown of select according to the value that user has selected.
The code I have tried is:

App.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedColor = '';

  colors = [
    {
      name: 'yellow',
      value: '#ffff00'
    },
    {
      name: 'red',
      value: '#ff3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'blue',
      value: '#0000ff'
    }
  ];

  onChange(value){
    this.selectedColor = value;
  }
}
```

App.component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" [compareWith]="compareObjects" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selected.color}">
  <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color.value}" [ngValue]="datas">{{color.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

But It is getting my requirement only on Windows but not on mac. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if is what you are looking for, I think your code must be,

Something like this.

**HTML**

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="selected" [compareWith]="compareObjects"
         [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selected.color}">
         <option *ngFor="let color of colors" 
               [ngStyle]="{'background': color.value}" [ngValue]="color"> 
               {{color.name}}
         </option>
    </select>
```

***your variable name is differ from the .ts file, thats why your code won't worked.**

Answer (score 0):

**you are iterating the wrong list **

1. In your typescript the list name is colors
2. but you are trying to iterate the list data which is not there in your type script.
3. So,change the data list to colors list in option tag and also change the ngModel name in HTML page.
4. and then it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your html part should be something like this

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" [compareWith]="compareObjects"
         [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selected.color}">
         <option *ngFor="let color of colors" 
               [ngStyle]="{'background': color.value}" [ngValue]="color"> 
               {{color.name}}
         </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not Sure but please check with adding [ngClass] for binding the color either on the selected option or the dropdown where you need. Hope this will work...

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selected" [compareWith]="compareObjects"
             [ngClass]="{'background-color': selected.color}">
             <option *ngFor="let color of colors" 
                   [ngClass]="{'background': color.value}" [ngValue]="color"> 
                   {{color.name}}
             </option>
    </select>
```